# cannot use a scalar values as an array

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress, scalar

i am trying to access to db wp but from php , and it's an operation that i 've done many times with the same script that it's down, but this time i obtain cannot use a scalare values as an array at the latest line of this code, why? I don't understand.

```
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
if (!$dbcnx) {
  exit('<p>poroppoppopopero ' .
      'this is the time of war.</p>');
}

if (!@mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')) {
  exit('<p>Unable to locate the joke ' .
      'database at this time pe pe pe pe pe pe pe</p>');
}



$result= @mysql_query ("SELECT  * FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 30");

    if (!$result){

            exit ('inserimento  non avvenuto'.mysql_error());

    }

    $cont1=1;
    $cont2=1; 
    $cont3=1; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){    


 $id[$cont1]= $row['ID'];
```

Comment: Yes, you can't use scalar as array (like `$a = 5; $a['someKey']`)

Comment: Declare `$id` as an array first:

`$id = array();`

Also, the 'cont1` etc. etc. etc. thing seems like a junky way to do it.

Comment: Ok Remy thank so much, now all is ok